# Navigation bar that moves with zoom, becomes unaligned [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment, zooming

I have a small problem with my horizontal navigation bar. On Chrome, the nav bar is perfectly inline with the width of the above banner, taking up the whole space, but only at 100% and 110% zooms. Any other zoom level ruins the alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/UdSrD/1/

```
    <please ignore this code, it is only here because it has to be>
    <all relevent code in above link>
```

In both the HTML & CSS, I have added a large blank space before and after the relevant code. Please if somebody knows how I fix this, I would be greatly thankful.

I am such a perfectionist with stuff like this so I need it fixed.

Thank's for your time!

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant bits of HTML and CSS? Then you can also remove the "ignorable" code.

Answer (score 1):

please make the following changes in css 
the width of the nave is more

////line index :51

```
ul.horizontal    
width: 100%;
```

/// line    index:59

```
ul.horizontal li  
width: 233.5px;
```

Comment: in the ul.horizontal, width actually doesnt do anything.
And as for the li width you suggested, it is far too small. This may be an issue beyond whati have included in my jsfiddle, and may be more to do with my attempts at making the site responsive. Thanks for your time!